# Python XPath - find sibling of element containing Text A OR Text B

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Fellows,

I'm scraping some download links. On the target website, each target download link sometimes appears after the text **'Application Proof (1st submission)'** and sometimes after the text **'PHIP (1st revised proof)'**. My current code only scrapes the links following 'Application Proof (1st submission)':

```
all_proofs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Application Proof (1st submission)')]/following-sibling::a[contains(.,'Full Version')]")
```

Is there any way to use an OR logic in this XPath to scrape in both scenarios and get a single list of links, according to the order in which they appear in the website's source code? The logic would be approximately:

```
all_proofs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Application Proof (1st submission)' OR 'PHIP (1st revised proof)')]/following-sibling::a[contains(.,'Full Version')]")
```

Unfortunately there isn't another workaround to use instead of this logic, since:

1. I can't simply scrape all download links that contain 'Full Version', since some of those links do not fit my criteria, only the ones that follow the text 'Application Proof (1st submission)' **OR** 'PHIP (1st revised proof)' do.
2. I can't scrape **one list of links** that follow the 'Application Proof (1st submission)' text, then scrape **another list of links** that follow the 'PHIP (1st revised proof)' and finally join them together, since I need this list to be in the exact same order as the links appear in the website's source code.

Would appreciate your help!

Comment: Please let me know if my answer resolved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `OR` operator inside XPath.
Your XPath expression could be something like this:

```py
all_proofs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Application Proof (1st submission)') or contains(text(),'PHIP (1st revised proof)')]/following-sibling::a[contains(.,'Full Version')]")
```